# STM32 - PC serial communication

Tags: usb, serial, communication, uart, stm32

What are the available options or ways to connect the STM32 discovery board using UART to a PC via USB or the serial port? What is the required hardware/cables?

Comment: Plenty, and its been covered here before.  Get an ftdi cable if you have no further decision drivers, but consider removing and taping up the 5v lead to limit the damage from connecting its non-keyed header to your board backwards.

Comment: Is it STM32 **F4** DISCOVERY board? If it's so, you can use STM32's USB as UART device. See this [example code](http://vedder.se/2012/07/usb-serial-on-stm32f4/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris mentioned, you can buy a FTDI RS232-USB converter.  They're really popular and are cheap.  Here's one:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716

Simply hook up the TX & RX headers on the board to your microcontroller, download the driver from FTDI, open up a terminal and go!

Comment: How do I receive the data on the PC ? I want to use it in a C/C++ program or in MATLAB